# Updating Django mixin subclassed instances

Tags: python, django, mixins

I am using my custom permission mixin on several of my apps's models (not all).

For the case when I need to merge from the "old - context" permission to the "new - context" permission I want to have function which changes the corresponding permission reference attribute in all models, which subclassed this mixin.

How do I know which models subclassed this permission mixin and that they have the inherited permission reference attribute?

In fact I want to have such function in my mixin:

```
class WorkspaceManagedMixin(models.Model):

    workspace = models.ForeignKey(Workspace)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    @classmethod
    def merge_to(cls, from_wspace, to_wspace):
        """
        Reallocating workspace's objects to other workspace.
        """

        workspace_managed_models = []  # HOW TO GET THIS?

        try:
            with transaction.atomic():
                for model in workspace_managed_models:
                    model.objects.filter(
                        workspace=from_wspace,
                    ).update(workspace=to_wspace)
        except IntegrityError as e:  # or DatabaseError
            raise e
```

The subclassed models can be in in other django applications in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Uff. Digging around the Internet I found now `__subclasses__()` and this in the Django itself:

```
[subclass for subclass in m.__subclasses__()
            if issubclass(subclass, models.Model)]
```

I assume it needs to be a) recursive, b) converted to set due to potential duplicates.